# Pass a variable on multiple views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to pass a variable on multiple views in order to perform an UPDATE on multiple views ( editScadenza and elaborazioneScadenza).
Or do you know another simpler solution?

**ScadenzaController.php**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data['scadenzaRecuperata'] = \App\Scadenza::find($id);

    return view('scadenze.editScadenza', $data);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'titolo'=>'required',
        'termine_stimato'=>'required',
        'responsabile'=>'required',
        'tipologia_id'=>'required',
        'giorni_avviso'=>'required',
    ],
    [
        'titolo.required'=>'Il titolo é obbligatorio',
        'termine_stimato.required' => 'Il termine stimato é obbligatoria',
        'responsabile.required' => 'Il responsabile é obbligatorio',
        'tipologia_id.required' => 'Il tipo é obbligatorio',
        'giorni_avviso.required'=> 'I giorni di avviso sono obbligatori',
    ]);

    $scadenza = \App\Scadenza::find($id);

    $now = Carbon::now();
    $end = Carbon::parse($scadenza->termine_stimato);
    $length = $end->diffInDays($now);

    $scadenza->titolo = $request->input('titolo');
    $scadenza->termine_stimato = date_create($request->input('termine_stimato'))->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    $scadenza->responsabile = $request->input('responsabile');
    $scadenza->tipologia_id = $request->input('tipologia_id');
    $scadenza->processo_id = $request->input('processo_id');
    $scadenza->stato = $request->input('stato');
    $scadenza->giorni_avviso = $request->input('giorni_avviso');
    $scadenza->osservazioni  = $request->input('osservazioni');

    $scadenza->save();

    return redirect('scadenza');

}
```

Comment: Try to use view composer

Comment: Did you know, when you're passing the ID of a model to a function you can access it like so `public function edit (Scadenza $scadenza)` which you could then do `return view('scadenze.editScandenza', compact('scadenza');` 

It's one of laravel's great features and it saves you doing another DB query! :)

Comment: You should use view()->share (i.e https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views)

Answer (score 1):

The best recommended solution is to share variables from the controller function. If you need it just for 2, 3 views and all comes under the same controller then share it as usual:

```
public function function_nameX($id)
{
  ..
  return view('scadenze.viewNameX')->withData($data);
}
```

...

```
public function function_nameY()
{
  ..
  return view('scadenze.viewNameY')->withData($data);
}
```

Do it even if you have views returned from multiple controllers. Because this is the most convenient way.

**To share a variable with all views in your project, share it from AppServiceProvider's boot() function like:**

```
public function boot()
{
  $data['scadenzaRecuperata'] = \App\Scadenza::find($id);
  View::share('data', $data);
}
```

> View Composer also help to bind specific data to view in different
>   ways. You can directly bind variable to specific view or to all views.
>   For Example you can create your own directory to store your view
>   composer file according to requirement. and these view composer file
>   through Service provide interact with view.

Here is the [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers).

Comment: I use the UPDATE form in two views. Is it possible that this thing conflicts? Because in the edit page it works, in the other it is not.
But I used the same form.

Comment: You will definitely get the variable/object sent from the controller. You may not have the same values in both cases. Try: `dd($name_of_variable);` from controller before you send it to the view. You won't get the same or you may have different code in your views.

Comment: So the situation is strange.
From the view I make an UPDATE (see updated code). I try to get the values ​​in the controller (works). If I print dd () before $ this-> validate ($ request) I see the values ​​if I insert it after this code I do not get the dd ();

Comment: Because the validation fails and Laravel redirects back. You have to print the error in the view. Take `count($errors)` in the view. @CarmineRub

Answer (score 1):

To share data with views you can set a view Composer

in **app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php** into `boot()` method

```
public function boot() {

  view()->composer('scadenze.editScadenza', function($view) {

    $data = \App\Scadenza::find(request()->id);

    $view->with('data', $data);
  });

}
```

For more date, see [Laravel View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers)

- if you need to share only with one: `composer('VIEW_NAME', ...)`
- If you need to share the data with more than one: `composer(['VIEW_NAME_1', 'VIEW_NAME_2'], ...)`
- If you need to share with all views: `composer('*', ...)`